# Assign row names and save multiple text files in one go with R

Tags: r

I wanted to make 6 random data sets for practice and used this code:

```r
mypath <- "C:/Users/***"  
A <- function(x)(matrix(round(runif(100, 0, 10^5)), nrow = 100))
rownames(x) <- paste0("Gene", 1:100)
```

I wanted to save 6 files named sample1-6.txt containing each different random numbers in one go, so I tried to write a for loop:

```r
for (i in 1:6) {write.table(A(x), file = paste0(mypath, paste("Sample", i, "txt", sep = ".")), quote = F, sep ="\t")
}
```

the problem is it makes a matrix like this in the text file:

```
 [,1]
  [1,] 87207
  [2,] 39773
  [3,] 66859
  [4,] 43813
```

but I wanted the files to be like this without manually running the codes every time:

```r
Gene1   87207
Gene2   39773
Gene3   66859
Gene4   43813
```

Is there a way to put `rownames(x)` in the loop or in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
A <- function(x){
  z = matrix(round(runif(4, 0, 10^5)), nrow = 4)
  rownames(z) <- paste0("Gene", 1:4)
  z
}

for (i in 1:3) {
  print(A())
}

       [,1]
Gene1 95184
Gene2 45595
Gene3 28377
Gene4 34266
       [,1]
Gene1 48586
Gene2 68974
Gene3 34566
Gene4 33815
       [,1]
Gene1 76261
Gene2   678
Gene3 89750
Gene4 79978
```

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot man, I changed my code according to this and it works!

Comment: @RezaKhayami, another tip: if you receive an answer that works and are not waiting for a "better" exampl, you should click the ✔ next to the answer to mark it as accepted. This gives the answerer credit and notifies others that the question has a solution.

Answer (score 2):

@R. Schifini beat me to the answer, so I'll make some style comments:

- `"*"` has a specific regex meaning in some strings; try to avoid it in toy examples.
- If you want your code to be more portable, do not start/end strings that represent paths to files/directories with `/` or `\`; those delimiters are OS specific.
- In the same vein, using `paste()` to construct paths is less portable than using `file.path()`, which will automatically insert the OS-specific path delimiter.
- Functions that do not need arguments can be written without arguments. For example, this works just as well:

```
A <- function() {    ## notice, no "x"
  z = matrix(round(runif(4, 0, 10^5)), nrow = 4)
  rownames(z) <- paste0("Gene", 1:4)
  z
}
```

- Function definitions should be enclosed in curly braces `{}`, not parentheses.
- Your `for` loop is a bit hard to read on the web, especially on mobile devices. Try to break up long lines. Compare this:

```
   for (i in 1:6) {write.table(A(x), file = paste0(mypath, paste("Sample", i, "txt", sep = ".")), quote = F, sep ="\t")
}
```

to this:

```
for (i in 1:6) {
    write.table(
        A(x), 
        file = paste0(mypath, paste("Sample", i, "txt", sep = ".")), 
        quote = F, 
        sep ="\t"
    )
}
```

None of what I've said is set in stone. Check out these style guides:
http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html
https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.html

And congratulations on a well written first question. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thank you, this was so helpful. As you can see i'm new to R so i really appreciate  this